# Why do I get null after I initialized a string?

Tags: java, string, null, println

I don't understand why Sp1.location returns NULL. If I run the program it seams I can initialize location successfully. I have code a attribute as an integer in a similar way, but that gave me no problems.

```
public class Database {

    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Add a new spawnpoint.\n");

        System.out.println("State the name of this spawnpoint: ");


        Spawnpoints Sp1 = new Spawnpoints(getSpawnName());

        System.out.println("Done");
        System.out.println("Location: " + Sp1.getLocation()); //return as null

    }

    public static String spawnName;

    public static String getSpawnName() {

        spawnName = userInput.next();
        return spawnName;
    }

    public void setSpawnName(String spawnName) {
        this.spawnName = spawnName;
    }
}


// Import libraries
import java.util.*;
```

This is my other class

```
public class Spawnpoints extends Database {


        // Define scanner, so you can accept user input
        static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

             // Define attributes of Spawnpoints


            private String location;
            private String iniLocation;


    // Creator, method for creating a instance of Spawnpoints. Will be the actual spawnpoints
    // I include a iniLocation so no user input is asked when calling on getLocation. 

    public Spawnpoints(String spawnName) {
        getIniLocation();

    }

    // Setters & Getters getLocation
    private String getIniLocation() {
        System.out.println("State the location of this spawnpoint:\n");
        pokemon = userInput.next ();
        return iniLocation;
    }

    public void setIniLocation(String iniLocation) {
        this.iniLocation = iniLocation;
    }


    public String getLocation() {
        location = iniLocation;
        return location;
    }


    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }



    public static void main (String[] args) {


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not setting the **`location`** , you are assigning input to **`pokemon`** instead of **`iniLocation`** and when you call function to get location you get back the value of  `iniLocation` which has not been assigned any value so hence null. Read comments in code

```
private String getIniLocation() {
    System.out.println("State the location of this spawnpoint:\n");
    pokemon = userInput.next (); // remove this
    iniLocation = userInput.next (); // with this
    return iniLocation;
}
```

and it's a good practice if you initialize your `scanner` object in constructor.

```
class AnyClass{
 Scanner scan;
  public AnyClass(){
    scan= new Scanner(System.in);
  }
}
```